# GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync, CopyAsync, AsStreamForRead not implemented in Uno Platform. Workarounds?

Tags: uno-platform

I tried to use the following methods, but all of them appeared as **not implemented** in Uno (Android). What can I do?

Is there any Xamarin.Essentials **alternative**?

Or other **NuGet package**?

Or should I use **native implementations** on each platform?

And is it even possible to **implement it** in Uno directly?

```
var pdfFile = StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(..);
pdfFile.CopyAsync(..);
(await pdfFile.OpenReadAsync()).AsStreamForRead(); // AsStreamForRead() not implemented
```

I'm using v1.45.0 of Uno.UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David Oliver [pointed out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58137364/1830814),

> Uno hasn't implemented most of the Windows.StorageFile APIs, as for
>   the most part there are alternatives available in System.IO, which
>   will work cross-platform.

So...

1. To **open file from the app package** we can set its build action to `Embedded Resource` instead of `Content`. And instead of `StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync()` method we can use this code:

   ```
   public Stream GetStreamFromResourceFile(string filename, Type callingType = null)
   {
       var assembly = (callingType ?? GetType()).Assembly;
       string foundResourceName = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().FirstOrDefault(r => r.EndsWith(filename, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
       if (foundResourceName == null)
           throw new FileNotFoundException("File was not found in application resources. Ensure that the filename is correct and its build action is set to 'Embedded Resource'.", filename);
       return assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(foundResourceName);
   }
   ```
2. to **copy** a file

   ```
   await pdfFile.CopyAsync(..);
   ```

   we change to:

   ```
   await pdfFile.CopyToAsync(newFile);
   ```
3. and to get **a stream** for read

   ```
   (await pdfFile.OpenReadAsync()).AsStreamForRead();
   ```

   we use:

   ```
   File.OpenRead(pdfFile);
   ```

So in the end we have:

```
        string filename = "File.pdf";
        var pdfFile = GetStreamFromResourceFile(filename, GetType());
        string newFilePath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, filename);
        using (var newFile = File.Create(newFilePath))
        {
            await pdfFile.CopyToAsync(newFile);
        }

        var fileStream = File.OpenRead(newFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Uno hasn't implemented most of the `Windows.StorageFile` APIs, as for the most part there are alternatives available in `System.IO`, which will work cross-platform.

If you're trying to display a pdf, however, there's no cross-platform option currently. On Android the best way to display a pdf is to launch an intent, on iOS it's possible to display the pdf in a `WebView`.

#### Partial example code for Android:

```cs
        public async Task Read(CancellationToken ct, string filePath)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);

            var file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
            var contentUri = Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(ContextHelper.Current, _fileProviderAuthority, file);

            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
            intent.SetDataAndType(contentUri, "application/pdf");

            StartActivity(intent);
        }
```

#### Partial example code for iOS:

```xml
                    <ios:WebView 
                                 Source="{Binding FilePath}"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not trying to open a PDF in an external app. No. I want to get a file from app package (build action = Content), to copy a file and to convert it to a stream

Comment: Ok, I'll try to use System.IO.File, but how about async-await? Should I wrap every call to file APIs in a Task.Run() to run it async? Wouldn't it exhaust thread pool?